# Getting user from db and appending to element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This might be a simple question but have kept me busy for the best part of a hour.

I have the following script which generates all active reservations, in the table `reservations`

```
require("../includes/connect.php");
function dispAllReservations(){
    $i= 1;
    global $db;
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM
        reservations WHERE pickup_date > '$date'";
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $bookings = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    echo'<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class=
     "table-responsive gzblog-table" id="gzhotel-booking-booking-id">
     <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="date-th">Reservation ID</th>
                <th class="title-th">Car Group</th>
                <th>Pickup Date</th>
                <th>Return Date</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
               </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>';
    foreach($bookings as $booking){
        if($i%2 == 0){
            $class = 'odd';
        }
        else{
            $class = 'even';
        }
        echo' <tr class='.$class.'>';
        echo'<td>'.$booking['res_id'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$booking['car_group'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$booking['pickup_date'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$booking['return_date'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$booking['renter_name'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$booking['email'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>AMOUNT HERE</td>';
        echo'<td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fancybox" href="#email">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
        </td>';
        echo'<td><a class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
        </td>';
        echo'<td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm icon-delete">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
        </td>';
        echo'</tr>';
    }//foreach
    echo'</tbody>';
    echo'</table>';
   }//function
```

The output of the script generates the following

[image]

### My Problem / Question

When delete button is clicked -- I need to ensure the correct reservation is deleted, same with the edit button, if edit button is clicked I need to ensure the correct user is edited.

**What I need to do**

- I'm guessing I would need to find a way to append the corresponding value for each user in the loop to the element.
- I was thinking of a textbox setting `display none` and then echoing the value inside the value attribute, but that didn't work...

I'm really stuck here any advise would be appreciated

**NOTE: All emails are fictional**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fancybox" href="#email" onclick="onDelete(your-id)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</a>

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fancybox" href="#email" onclick="onEdit(your-id)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</a>
```

Create this function:

```
<script>
    //Delete function
    function onDelete(id){
        $.ajax({
           // do someting
        });
    }

    // Edit function
    function onEdit(id){
        $.ajax({
           // do someting
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us at all how do you want to edit/delete you reservations, but based on the tags you used you can take this approach...

1) In your PHP script generate data attributes on rows or cells, like this:

```
<tr data-id="put_reservation_id_here">
```

2) And then use jQuery to hook actions to various elements in the table:

```
$('#gzhotel-booking-booking-id').on('click', '.icon-delete', function() {
   var reservationId = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
   // now you have reservation ID and do whichever AJAX call with it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes in your html and then get the data attribute value using javascript.

Example:

In your button:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm icon-delete" data-id="your_Id"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Replace your_Id with the correct id.

Then using javascript on your onClick event:

```
$(this).data('id');
```

This will retrieve the id that you need to handle the action.

Hope this helps.